# How do I add an object to an array each time I run a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to code a system where every time you enter new data and press add, it will create an object, and add that object into an array. But i am not sure how to add a new object to an array. Also I am not sure why my code is not in the yellow box.

```
var products = [];



class Product {

    constructor(productname, cost, quantity){
        this.productname = productname;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}


function addProduct(){

    var productname = document.getElementById('productName').value;
    var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

    tbody += '<tr><td>' + productname + '</td><td>' + cost + '</td><td>' + quantity + '</td><td>' + test + '</td><tr>';

      document.getElementById('tablebody').innerHTML = tbody;

      product();

//adding product to array

 function product(){

        products = new Product(productname, cost, quantity);
}
}

'''
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Is your `product` function actually defined **inside** your `addProduct` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `products` when you call `product` - use `push` - also pass the variables into `product` otherwise you'll get an error:

```
    product(productname, cost, quantity);

}

function product(productname, cost, quantity) {
    products.push(new Product(productname, cost, quantity));
}
```

Also close off your `addProducts` function with a brace:

```
    document.getElementById('tablebody').innerHTML = tbody;

    product();

}
```

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed OP's `product` function is actually defined within `addProduct` so those variables might not be in scope